# Why variables declared without var statement is global

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Consider the following code:

```
var somevar;
function(){
    newvar="SomeStr";
}();
```

I want to understand why does `newvar-->"SomeStr"` binding contained into a global namespace? From the spec, §11.13.1 "Simple Assignment (`=`)":

> The production *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* = *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 3. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 4. Throw a **SyntaxError** exception if the following conditions are all true:
>
>    - Type(*lref*) is Reference is **true**
>    - IsStrictReference(*lref*) is **true**
>    - Type(GetBase(*lref*)) is Environment Record
>    - GetReferencedName(*lref*) is either `"eval"` or `"arguments"`
> 5. Call PutValue(*lref*, *rval*).
> 6. Return *rval*.

`newvar` is an identifier. From §10.3.1 "Identifier Resolution":

> During execution of ECMAScript code, the syntactic production *PrimaryExpression* : *Identifier* is evaluated using the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Let *env* be the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. If the syntactic production that is being evaluated is contained in a strict mode code, then let *strict* be **true**, else let *strict* be **false**.
> 3. Return the result of calling GetIdentifierReference function passing *env*, *Identifier*, and *strict* as arguments.

GetIdentifierReference (*lex*, *name*, *strict*) is defined in its own section §10.2.2.1, which says:

> […] When called, the following steps are performed:
>
> 1. If *lex* is the value **null**, then
>
>    1. [*a*] Return a value of type Reference whose base value is **undefined**, whose referenced name is *name*, and whose strict mode flag is *strict*.
> 2. Let *envRec* be *lex*’s environment record.
> 3. Let *exists* be the result of calling the HasBinding(*N*) concrete method of *envRec* passing *name* as the argument *N*.
> 4. If *exists* is `true`, then
>
>    1. [*a*] Return a value of type Reference whose base value is *envRec*, whose referenced name is *name*, and whose strict mode flag is *strict*.
> 5. Else
>
>    1. [*a*] Let *outer* be the value of *lex*’s outer environment reference.
>    2. [*b*] Return the result of calling GetIdentifierReference passing *outer*, *name*, and *strict* as arguments.

Thus we have that after evaluating `newvar` identifier, reference with the name `newvar` and base value `undefined` will be returned. But when we've tried to invoke `PutValue(lref,rval)`  during the evaluating of `AssignmentExpression` we have

> 1. If Type(V) is not Reference, throw a ReferenceError exception.
> 2. Let base be the result of calling GetBase(V).
> 3. If IsUnresolvableReference(V), then
>
>    a. If IsStrictReference(V) is true, then
>
>    ```
>     i. Throw ReferenceError exception.
>    ```
>
>    b. Call the [[Put]] internal method of the global object, passing GetReferencedName(V) for the property name, W for the value, and false for the Throw flag.
> 4. Else if IsPropertyReference(V), then
>
>    a. If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is false, then let put be the [[Put]] internal method of base, otherwise let put be the special [[Put]] internal method defined below.
>
>    b. Call the put internal method using base as its this value, and passing GetReferencedName(V) for the property name, W for the value, and IsStrictReference(V) for the Throw flag.
> 5. Else base must be a reference whose base is an environment record. So,
>        a. Call the SetMutableBinding (10.2.1) concrete method of base, passing GetReferencedName(V), W, and IsStrictReference(V) as arguments.
> 6. Return.

Thus `SetMutableBinding` will call. But base is `undefined` and TypeError must be raised. Instead the `newvar--->"SomeStr"` binding will be added to a global namespace. Please explain me why?

Comment: Complete ans to your question 


[What is the function of the var keyword in ECMAScript 262 3rd Edition/Javascript 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript#answer-1471738)

Comment: @Pilot So why in the spec said that If lex is the value null, then a. Return a value of type Reference whose base value is **undefined**, whose referenced name is name, and whose strict mode flag is strict. Why the base value is not a global object environment?

Comment: I don't understand why you think a TypeError would be raised. You don't quote any part of the spec that throws any TypeError for any reason (relevant or otherwise).